# sharepoint survey grouping

Tags: survey-list

i created a survey with 20 questions but i also want to get some user info at first before starting to survey.
Like
your age :
your department :

then survey questions 1...next..20

by this way i want to get the results according to department.i want to group which department
gives which answers.
I can't find a way to do it,any way to do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make these questions part of the survey and then do paging to move into the rest of the survey questions.

Comment: but how about analysing/reporting answers according to personal questions.

Comment: Example : 25 years old people generally gives the answer : good... 30 years old people gives the answers : not so good... and so i want to group answers,analyse the survey according to user profiles i took in the first part of the survey